# store a reference to a script to attach at runtime

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Another best practice question.  I have a list of ScriptableObjects now (thanks to LearningCocos2d) which defines a list of sprites I can load at runtime.

I followed this tutorial:  http://www.jacobpennock.com/Blog/?p=670

In order to drive some custom behaviour, I want different scripts applied to my various in-game objects when I instantiate them.  What's the best way to store the references to the desired scripts I want to apply?

[Edit] Some more details:

My scriptable object is a simple list of serializable objects.  I have a series of defined scripts that I want to attach to the objects I define.  Unity however does not seem to allow me to store a reference to the script using the below method.

```
public class TestList : ScriptableObject {
    public List<MotionSpriteData> MotionSprites;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class MotionSpriteData {
    public Component motionPath;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a class that loads all the scripts into an array. This class does not necessarily have to be a MonoBehaviour, but for this example it will be.

You have two options:

1. Drag and drop the scripts into the array via the *Editor*.
2. Or put all the scripts in the `Resources/Scripts/` folder so that they can be loaded at run time.

   ```
   public class ScriptManager : MonoBehaviour 
   {
      public Object [] list;

      void Awake()
      {
          // Comment this line if you used step 1 above.
          list = Resources.LoadAll("Scripts"); 

          gameObject.AddComponent(list[0].name);
      }
   }
   ```

Now you can use your own logic to determine which `GameObject` gets which `Script`, but that should be trivially easy for you.

[image]

Comment: You're going to have to help me out with this a bit more.  How is this array built?

Comment: I am guessing the answer to my question is to simply store a string reference to the script name.  Let me know if there is a better way.

Comment: Make the array as I have suggested above.

Comment: I added more detail to my question.  I made the type "Component" in my object, but Unity won't let me store the reference.

Comment: @GregoryJohnson I have updated my answer. You should be able to load the scripts now.

Comment: Declaring the Object type is probably not the best way to go.  But, I would give you part marks since I learned that it was in fact possible due to your suggested answer.  But, you probably want to use stronger typing.  Not sure why I didn't find my answer sooner in my searching.  Anyways, hope that helps you.

Comment: Where are those "part marks" (that's a joke lol you don't have to give me anything). There is logical reason for using `Object`. The scripts are kept as that type in the resource folder. They don't need to be casted to a type before adding them as components, so I'm saving that step.

Answer (score 0):

Just coming back to this question, since my original answer is actually incorrect as someone pointed out.  Monoscript stores references to individual scripts (strongly typed), but Monoscript is only valid in the UnityEditor namespace.

Since my question is about best practice, I offer what I have done as a proposal, but since I'm still only 2 months into Unity dev, I'm interested in other opinions.  What I ended up doing is building prefabs for each object type, which leverages the power of the Unity WYSIWYG interface.  Thus, storing references to scripts becomes irrelevant, since the prefab contains all the behaviours I need.

Since I still need a data layer for my game to drive the game play, my scriptable objects have hence become simpler.  The problem of referencing the script becomes instead the problem of referencing the prefab which contains the scripts.

FunctionR has described in his answer how you can use Resources.Load to load content at runtime.  However, my question is about how to reference the individual script I want.  What I have done is simply store a path to the resource (ie: prefab) I want loaded, as a string.

Answer (score -2):

Unity script assets are of type "MonoScript".  Simply declare a variable as this type and it will work.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoScript.html